# excel file uploading in php

Tags: php, excel, file, uploading

i am working on a project in php and trying to upload an excel file to server but it fails every time. My code files are below:   all functions modules are working correctly in newupload.php file given below, but move_uploaded_file function is not working and file is not moving to destination. Please check my code and help please

```
//this is first page
    //index.php

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>

        <form action="newupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select image to upload:
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>

    //second page
    //newupload.php

    <?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);//destination
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);//returns extension of file
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = filesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
       }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
//checks whether file is excel or not
    if($FileType != "xlsx" ) {
        echo "Sorry, Excel files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";// this error arising in my program
        }
    }
    ?>
```

//please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to print the destination full path.

Comment: Also, try giving permissions to uploading folder.

Comment: UPDATE:
@Programming Student I just checked that this program is working correctly for small size files and not working for large files.
File i want to upload is about 8MB thats why it is not working and small files just 5kb or else uploading successfully. Although i have set size limit in index.php Please help

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPeXCEL Class  http://blog.mayflower.de/561-Import-and-export-data-using-PHPExcel.html

The code is

```
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("MyExcel.xlsx");
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    echo "<br>The worksheet ".$worksheetTitle." has ";
    echo $nrColumns . ' columns (A-' . $highestColumn . ') ';
    echo ' and ' . $highestRow . ' row.';
    echo '<br>Data: <table border="1"><tr>';
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
            $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $val = $cell->getValue();
            $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
            echo '<td>' . $val . '<br>(Typ ' . $dataType . ')</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```